# Azure DevOps Branch Security Inheritence not possible to toggle off

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops

I need to give specific users custom rights to perform certain actions. I assumed I could do this by toggling inheritence (below) to OFF and manually give the rights to the users. This however to do absolutely nothing since the permissions are still inherited from the users Security Groups. How do I go about to give select users **custom** permissions on a git branch?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inheritance is disabled, the current item takes all inherited permissions. If you want to set permission for specific users, search the user and set permission for him:

[image]

Comment: When I disable inheritance on a branch under "branch security"; inheritance is still in full effect. I have added the users I wish to give custom security rights to, but the inheritance overrides my custom settings. E.g. if I give the user rights to force push - which is disabled for all security groups - the user will display "Deny (Inherited)", even if I have explicitly toggled Inheritance off.

Comment: For most groups and almost all permissions, Deny overrides Allow. Check documentation here to see whether it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#inheritance-and-security-groups.